# Where do US public companies announce news?

Tags: united-states, stocks, news, corporate-governance

Where do US public companies announce significant news such as dividends, stock splits, new bond offerings, divestitures, mergers and acquisitions, hiring and resignations of corporate officers, etc.? How do they make these announcements? Is it through their website, a press release distribution service, an SEC filing, an analyst meeting, or ...? Is there any consistency in all this? Are there any regulations?

Answer (score 3):

Corporations provide press releases on their company websites and to the media (print, TV such as CNBC, electronic, web sites, etc.).  Newswires distribute that info (Bloomberg, DJ News, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

Public companies have to file a quarterly financial reports. These are almost always published on the "investor" section of their websites. These section frequently also include a news and press releases.

For example, [see this](https://investor.apple.com/investor-relations/default.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

The Securities and Exchange Commission (SEC) does not have any specific regulations dictating how public companies announce significant news. The most common way these announcements are made is through press releases, which can be distributed through a press release distribution service, on the company's website, or filed with the SEC. Companies may also announce significant news through analyst meetings or other investor relations events. There is no one consistent way these announcements are made, and companies may vary in how they approach this.